Terraform Create AWS Tag and Value based off of a variable
We have different environments within our AWS infrastructure which are stored in a CloudFormation export. I am automating a daily shutdown down of Dev environments and the script checks to see if a certain tag exists on any EC2 in the environment. I would like to write my TF in such a manner that if the "environment" is "dev" we create a tag with a value "whatever" otherwise the value is blank. This is what I have so far:
data "aws_cloudformation_export" "envshort" {
name = "${var.mycode}—EnvShort"
}

tags = merge(
{
scheduler-policy = data.aws_cloudformation_export.envshort.value == "dev" ? "weekdays" : ""
},
local.tags,
)

When I run my plan, nothing is created it seems to just disappear.
of course when I do:
tags = merge(
{
scheduler-policy = "weekdays"
},
local.tags,
)

Everything works as expected. So my question is: Can I do this and my syntax is just wrong or is it just not possible.

Are you sure the value of data.aws_cloudformation_export.envshort.value is "dev"?

I am sure, these values are all included in the LZ creation automation.

And yet Terraform is behaving as if data.aws_cloudformation_export.envshort.value is not "dev". What happens if you just set it to scheduler-policy = data.aws_cloudformation_export.envshort.value and run terraform plan? What does it say it is setting the scheduler-policy tag to then?

I figured it out finally, with some prompting from Mark B, and with the answers from: "Conditional tags in terraform" provided by Marcin and Kyle Gibson I was able to write the solution.
Here is the solution I came up with:
tags = merge(
data.aws_cloudformation_export.envshort.value == "dev" ? {
"eng-scheduler-policy" = ""
} :
{
"eng-scheduler-policy" = "weekdays" 
},
local.tags,
)

